# Conditional Join fields on SQL

Tags: join, conditional-statements

I'm doing a left join on 2 tables

```sql
Select *
From 
   Claims 
     Left Join
   Rates
        On 
           Claims.ID = Rates.ID
           AND Claims.Code = Rates.Code
           AND Claims.Date = Rates.Date
           AND Claims.Modifier = Rates.Modifier
```

I want to execute the modifier join field only if Claims Modifier has a value of 'A' and 'B'.  If Claims Modifier is either Null or has other values other than 'A' and 'B', I want to only execute the first 3 join fields (ID, Code and Date).

Answer (score 0):

if I understant your requirement correctly, you can change final close " AND Claims.Modifier = Rates.Modifier" as "AND (Claims.Modifier IN ('A', 'B') OR Claims.Modifier IS NULL)"

Comment: AND (Claims.Modifier In ('A', 'B') OR Claims.Modifier IS NULL) This statement works when claims modifier has a value of A or B but doesn't when it's NULL. When it's Null or not A or B, I don't want to execute the modifier join field, I want only to execute the first 3 join fields only